# Returning variable name from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to return a variable name from an array?

I have an array with 5 variables. Each variable is assigned a numeric value.

I am trying to find the highest value in the array and then alert its variable name, or possibly use that variable to do things with it.

```
        var vara = 0; //resultA
        var varb= 0; //resultB
        var varc= 0;  //resultC
        var vard= 0;  //resultD
        var vare= 0;  //resultE

function showResults() {
            var buckets = [vara, varb, varc, vard, vare];
            var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, buckets);


                alert(largest);



        }
```

The above code alerts the value of largest, but I want to find the corresponding variable, for instance vara instead of 3

Comment: Provide us with the code you've written so far. The languge you're using to describe the problem doesn't make sense, you cannot "return" things from arrays, and arrays don't "have variables". You cannot have "an array with 5 variables".

Comment: is this for some sort of code analysis tool? why would you need the name of a variable?

Comment: It's a quiz/questionnaire. The variables are global variables (buckets) that update based on a user's response. At the end of the questionnaire I want to take the variable (bucket) with the most answers and return a certain result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not. If you want to associate some name with value, thats what dictionaries for.

```
var obj = {"name": 123, "name2": 234}
obj.name3 = 345; // assign 345 to name3
var valueOfName3 = obj.name3; // get name3
```

If you want to get the largest value in this object (by [akonsu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809858/returning-variable-name-from-array/26809881#comment42193532_26809881)):

```
var largest = null;
var keyOfLargestVal = null;
for(var k in obj) { var v = obj[k];
 if (largest === null || v > largest){
   largest = v; keyOfLargestVal = k;
 }
}
```